# Maximum notifications per comment in GitHub

Tags: github

When using GitHub, I sometimes list several users with the @ sign to indicate that they should look at e.g. a pull request. The other day, I did this with about 20 people, and some of them were not properly notified.

Is there some limit on the number of people GitHub will send notifications to based on a single comment? If so, what is the limit?